# PHP Header redirect after form submit not working

Tags: php, sql, database, redirect

I have a snippet of code that posts information the user enters into a form, to the DB. After the last line of PHP that submits the data to the DB I have:

```
header("location:http://www.site.com/page.htm");
```

This doesn't seem to do anything. It still posts all the user info to the DB, but the page clears out and thats it. No redirect.

Here is the whole snippet:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $username = ($_POST['username']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
    $email = ($_POST['email']);
    $email2 = ($_POST['email2']);
    $password2 = ($_POST['password2']);
    $commname = ($_POST['commname']);
    $outpostname = ($_POST['outpost']);
    $special = ($_POST['specialty']);

    if($username == "" || $password == "" || $email == "" || $password2 == "" || $email2 == "" || $commname == "" || $outpostname == "" || $special == "no"){
        echo "Please supply all required fields!";
    }elseif(strlen($username) > 20){
        echo "Username must be less than 20 characters!";
    }elseif(strlen($email) > 100){
        echo "E-mail must be less than 100 characters!";
    }elseif(strlen($email2) > 100){
        echo "E-mail verify must be less than 100 characters!";
    }elseif(strlen($commname) > 20){
        echo "Your Commander's name must be less than 20 characters!";
    }elseif(strlen($outpostname) > 20){
        echo "Your Outpost's name must be less than 20 characters!";
    }else{
        $register1 = mysqli_query($myConnection,"SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `username`='$username'") or die(mysqli_error($myConnection));
        $register2 = mysqli_query($myConnection,"SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `email`='$email'") or die(mysqli_error($myConnection));
        if(mysqli_num_rows($register1) > 0){
            echo "That username is already in use!";
        }elseif(mysqli_num_rows($register2) > 0){
            echo "That e-mail address is already in use!";
        }else{
            $spec = ($_POST['specialty']);
            $comnam = ($_POST['commname']);
            $postnam = ($_POST['outpost']);                                                    
            $rand_col = rand(1,5); /*Number of Colonies that exist in the game*/
            $ins1 = mysqli_query($myConnection,"INSERT INTO `stats` (`username`,`credits`,`food`,`land`,`energy`,`turns`,`turns_max`,`gas`,`ore`,`population`,`buildeff`,`offpts`,`defpts`,`score`,`specialty`) VALUES ('$username',2000,2000,100,2000,30,30,2000,2000,500,100,0,0,0,'$spec')") or die(mysqli_error($myConnection));
            $ins2 = mysqli_query($myConnection,"INSERT INTO `unit` (`username`,`trainee`,`juggernaut`,`infantry`,`marauder`,`terminator`,`reconsq`,`prisoner`,`destroyer`,`colossus`) VALUES ('$username',100,0,50,0,0,0,0,0,0)") or die(mysqli_error($myConnection));
            $ins3 = mysqli_query($myConnection,"INSERT INTO `user` (`colonynum`,`username`,`password`,`email`,`specialty`,`commname`,`outpostname`) VALUES ('$rand_col','$username','".md5($password)."','$email','$spec','$comnam','$postnam')") or die(mysqli_error($myConnection));
            $ins4 = mysqli_query($myConnection,"INSERT INTO `structure` (`username`,`agridome`,`spaceport`,`barrack`,`researchfac`,`laserbat`,`factory`,`infirmary`,`trainingfac`) VALUES ('$username',1,0,5,0,0,0,1,1)") or die(mysqli_error($myConnection));
            header("location:http://www.site.com/page.php");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and yes I know, I should be using some SQL injection protection but cant get that working just yet.. that will come later ;)

Comment: Is the HTTP header case-sensitive?  Or at least in certain browsers?  Somethings things can be picky like that.  Try:  `header("Location: http://www.site.com/page.htm");`

Comment: I've tried capitals, no space between location: and the URL, same effect.

Comment: Checked that nothing is output at all before the redirect?

Comment: what do you mean by output? I have a lot going on before the redirect.

Comment: [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) documentation. First couple lines explain about no output.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
header("location:http://www.site.com/page.php");
```

to

```
header("location: http://www.site.com/page.php");
```

Also, if u even have one character outputed before the header command (i.e. body of the http request) it will fail. **Turn on PHP error reporting to see if this is the case.**

Output characters can even be white chars, something between the `<?php` and the beginning of the page.

Like:
======page starts below this line=======

```
   <?php
```

Notice there are white characters before the `<?php`

Comment: This is not the issue.

Comment: I've tried with spaces and no spaces. I realize now its because I have a lot more going on than just a header function, so it will not work. going to have to try another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If your header isn't working, it is because your script produced an output (e.g. an error message, because of unchecked GET parameters), before the header is sent. Check your webserver's error log, which should contain the information, what exactly fails.

Comment: I don't get the downvote here; this is the correct answer, as is the other answer.  No output may be sent before a header call.

Answer (score 1):

All headers need to be sent to the browser before any other type of output (error messages, HTML, Javascript, etc).

In your case, you have a lot going on in the script before you call `header()`, and one or more of those lines of code are generating output. Once that happens, you can no longer send header information.

To fix the problem, determine what is generating output and remove it, or move the `header()` call nearer to the top of the script before any `echo` statements, `mysqli*` statements, or any other line that can produce output.

Comment: so would some form of javascript work to redirect once the form is submitted? I only want it to run if all the requirements have been met on the form though.

Comment: That is one possible approach. The other approach is to buffer all of your output, and only send it to the browser if the conditions are not met and you don't intend to redirect. See the [Output Control Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) documentation for details.

Comment: buffering out the output doesn't seem to be an option for me. I need all that info in there. Im going to have to go with the JS approach and figure out how to get it to load once all conditions have been met and after it submits the user data to the database

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work using:

```
$url = '/page.php';
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
```